Is Compose MutableState atomic?
I'm trying reproduce race condition in Jetpac Compose state like this:
@Composable
fun CounterContentAtomicCheck(){
    var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    launch {
                        repeat(100000) {
                            counter += 1
                        }
                    }
                    launch {
                        repeat(100000) {
                            counter += 1
                        }
                    }

        }
        Text(text = "Counter: $counter")
    }
}

Output 200000.
Can we say that atomicity is guaranteed?

No, MutableState is not atomic.
The reason why this still works is that you do not actually have any concurrent access. Although you launch two coroutines, they both run on the Main dispatcher which only has a single thread. Since the coroutines do not suspend at any time the first coroutine is executed exclusively, and only then the second coroutine starts, now also running exclusively.
When you change the first launch to launch(Dispatchers.Default) both coroutines will now run on separate threads and you will observe a lot of concurrent access swallowing many of the updates: In my test run the final count was only 112258. And that observation now matches the expectation of a non-atomic data structure.
